# Highcharts click function update series and cancel previous update

Tags: highcharts

I built a line chart with more than 50 series: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/yj5hLg7m/2/)

Now I want to highlight one series by button click (opacity: 1). When I highlight another series, the first one should get its original opacity of 0.1 again.

With only two series I can achieve this by doing this:

```
    $('#func1').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#Weltweit').highcharts();  
    chart.series[3].update({opacity: 0.1}); 
    chart.series[4].update({opacity: 1});
                              });

$('#func2').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#Weltweit').highcharts(); 
    chart.series[3].update({opacity: 1});
    chart.series[4].update({opacity: 0.1}); 
                              });
```

But I cannot do this with 50 series because it takes too long to calculate. Is there a way to cancel the previous update before doing a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the update method with `redraw` parameter set to `false` and redraw chart after loop:

```
chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
    s.update({
        ...
    }, false);
});

chart.redraw();
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3a9bfjgd/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#redraw

Answer (score 0):

You can read here, similar with your problem: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.point.events.select